# jq how to get all parents of a specific child

Tags: json, jq

Hello I've the following json and try to get all parents who have the "linux-image-amd64"

```
{
    "web-prode-01.example.de": "ERROR: Problem encountered installing package(s). Additional info follows:\n\nchanges:\n    ----------\n    linux-image-amd64:\n        ----------\n        new:\n        old:\n            6.1.55-1\nerrors:\n    - Running scope as unit: run-rad31bddd35ec452b9d67fef004ce3daf.scope\n      E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)",
    "web-prode-04.example.de": {
        "linux-image-amd64": {
            "old": "5.10.197-1",
            "new": "5.10.205-2"
        },
        "linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64": {
            "old": "",
            "new": "5.10.205-2"
        }
    },
    "lmrelaunch.example.de": {
        "linux-image-6.1.0-0.deb11.13-amd64": {
            "old": "",
            "new": "6.1.55-1~bpo11+1"
        },
        "linux-image-amd64": {
            "old": "6.1.38-4~bpo11+1",
            "new": "6.1.55-1~bpo11+1"
        }
    }   
}
```

I tried `jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k) \(.[$k]."linux-image-amd64")"'` but I just got one entry instead of two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the context `has` that key. Also, to prevent the string from failing when trying to apply `has` on it, either filter for `objects`, or suppress the error with `?`. In either case, use this condition to filter the results using `select`.

```bash
keys[] as $k | .[$k] | objects | select(has("linux-image-amd64"))
# or
keys[] as $k | .[$k] | select(has("linux-image-amd64")?)
```

```json
{
  "linux-image-6.1.0-0.deb11.13-amd64": {
    "old": "",
    "new": "6.1.55-1~bpo11+1"
  },
  "linux-image-amd64": {
    "old": "6.1.38-4~bpo11+1",
    "new": "6.1.55-1~bpo11+1"
  }
}
{
  "linux-image-amd64": {
    "old": "5.10.197-1",
    "new": "5.10.205-2"
  },
  "linux-image-5.10.0-27-amd64": {
    "old": "",
    "new": "5.10.205-2"
  }
}
```

You can then construct your output using `$k`, e.g.:

```bash
keys[] as $k | .[$k] | select(has("linux-image-amd64")?) | $k
```

```
lmrelaunch.example.de
web-prode-04.example.de
```

Comment: The output construction is interesting ... and a mystery to me.  Why isn't `keys[]`, the assignment to `$k`, the final output?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Not sure if I correctly understood your question. `$k` was bound to the values of `keys[]` in the original (top-level) context, producing three instances: `"lmrelaunch.example.de"`, `"web-prode-01.example.de"`, and `"web-prode-04.example.de"`. After descending into those keys with `.[$k]`, the root node isn't accessible anymore (so `keys` would now evaluate to something else). Then, `select(…)` eliminates one of the three "timelines", and the contexts of the remaining two become the output of my first example, their respective values of `$k` (the "final output") that of my last.